# SOAP library in C

Tags: c, soap

I am looking for a SOAP Library for C. I know there is gSOAP. What other options do I have?

Comment: No it is working fine. But my intension here is to derive from the experience from somebody who has used a C SOAP library.

Comment: Then ask that explicitly to make your question worthy of posting :). You wouldn't walk into an investment management firm and ask "which mutual fund should I invest in?" without explaining your current needs and plans. This is all to say that it's a fair enough question, but the way you phrased it is rather poor.

Comment: What's wrong with gsoap? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: gsoap is fine. The point is to actually research and what else options I have before committing to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [blog](http://cwebservices.blogspot.com/) entry. I know it's C++, but I have had good results with Apache's AXIS. If you can use a C++ compiler, you can wrap around a C library to your generated classes.